# lerna ERR! yarn run build stderr: error Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux, npx

I am trying to run build command "npx lerna run build" but getting below error.
node version- v10.20.1
yarn version- 1.16.0
npm version-  3.10.10
npx version- 6.14.4
lerna version -3.16.1

lerna ERR! yarn run build stderr:
error Command failed with exit code 2.

lerna ERR! yarn run build exited 2 in 'parcel-plugin-gadget-builder'